# Progress bar ( Spinner ) won't change - set progressDrawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

this is my code from layout...

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rotate"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/b"
        android:visibility="gone"            />
```

(`b` is a PNG)

> android still showing default one [image]

then tried this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rotate"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rotate"
    android:visibility="gone"            />
```

as you can see I set progressDrawable to an drawable XML which I tried to copy from everywhere so I think the problem cant be there.
but anyway I will post it

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360">

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="7.0">

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#007DD6"
        android:endColor="#007DD6"
        android:startColor="#007DD6"
        android:angle="0"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

this is an extract from tutorials point

> but android still showing the default one

also I made this but I have a suspicion that is a terrible mistake

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/b"/>

</rotate>
```

but there is no way...

I am stuck no matter what I do Android still showing default one. anyone can help?

Comment: Plz edit your quesition systematically.

Comment: Use indeterminateDrawable , not progressDrawable. I posted a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use indeterminateDrawable , not progressDrawable.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rotate"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/b"
        android:visibility="gone"            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use android:progressDrawable="some value" for animation.

1)Assign some id to rotate tag

2)write this in your activity.java file

Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.id_of_your_rotate)

3)Retrieve the reference of ProgressBar

ProgressBar demo=new ProgressBar(this);

demo.setAnimation(anim);